# MySQL count(distinct(email) and Group By DATE(entrydate)

Tags: mysql, count, group-by, distinct

Having a bit of trouble with getting total unique records and grouping by date. The end result is I am getting totals per day but it is not using unique emails based on the distinct function. Here is my query...

```
SELECT count(distinct(emailaddress)), DATE(EntryDate)
FROM tblentries
group by   DATE(EntryDate)
ORDER BY DATE(EntryDate) desc
```

The results end up not de-duping the count for each day. Thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: Does that actually run?  The syntax for the select should be SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT emailaddress)... you have too many parentheses. Do you have null values in your aggregate columns?

Comment: What type is `EntryDate`? Is it `Date`? If not, why do you call it Date?

Comment: Yes, it runs fine. No... I do not get null values. EntryDate is a timestamp. I am using the date function to get the date without the time values.

Comment: @Jeremy FYI... Changing SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(emailaddress)) to SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT emailaddress) gives the same result.

Comment: what result are you getting that is showing you that the counts are not de-duping?  Just one row?  What do you get with [select count(distinct date(EntryDate)) from tblentries]?

Comment: @Jeremey Well... there are 116000 rows. Doing a plain distinct on emailaddress shows 31,000. The values I get back for the original query above is 116000 that average get about 4000 (+/-) results per day for the past 27 days. I just ran your query of [select count(distinct date(EntryDate)) from tblentries] and the result was 27.

Comment: @Jeremy Not sure if I was clear in my last comment... I guess what I mean is that I get 27 rows of data for each day for the past 27 days and they average about 4000 per day... Certainly more than 31000 unique entries. This is where I am basing it is as not de-duping the count.

Comment: @Jeremy If it help... Here are the results I get... [link](http://pastebin.com/WkCX0g3R)

Comment: That sounds right though. SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT) will only show you the distinct rows in the group you are grouping them by.  There will be overlap if a distinct email address logs has records on two days.  Are you looking for the number of never-before-seen email addresses for each day?

Comment: @Jeremy I am looking for total **unique** entries per day. I want to remove the duplicates from emailaddress via the query. I suppose that can also translate to never-before-seen for each day?

Comment: K, For the record, unique entries *per* day does not equal unique entries *in* a day.  I think you are looking for the latter, and your query was providing the former.  I supplied an answer below; we can address issues with it there.

Answer (score 4):

Based on the conversation, I believe what you are looking for is the number of distinct never-before-seen email addresses per day:

```
SELECT
    DATE(t.EntryDate) as RecordDate,
    COUNT(DISTINCT t.emailaddress) as NewEmailAddresses
FROM
    tblentries t
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT 1
        FROM tblentries t2
        WHERE
            t2.emailaddress = t.emailaddress
            AND DATE(t2.EntryDate) < DATE(t.EntryDate)
    )
GROUP BY
    DATE(t.EntryDate)
ORDER BY
    DATE(t.EntryDate) ASC;
```

This is off the top of my head, so it may not be right, and it will be slow, but I think this is in the right direction.  On a side note, if you plan on running this regularly, an index on emailaddress would be a good idea.

Let me know if this works.

Comment: Thanks, Jeremy. I tried the query but continues to run (after 5 min i stopped it). Thoughts? I do not plan to run this often and is a one time client request. Thanks for clarifying the difference as well.

Comment: Do you have an index on emailaddress?  If not, that would make a big difference.  If you do, well... hmm.  There are other things we can do, but letting the query run might be the simplest.  With 100K records, it shouldn't take much longer than 5 minutes.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs This is working fine for me also. But I afraid that it will affect the performance. How can I modify this for some more better performance ?

Comment: Making sure there is a primary key and an index on the emailaddress column would likely work in all but the most extreme circumstances.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs, I had a similar requirement and I used a query similar to your suggestion, but I receive the error, "Unknown table or alias 'r1' used in select query." where r1 and r2 are equivalent to your t and t2.

Comment: @Shyam you're probably referencing it in slightly the wrong place, or you misplaced a parenthesis somewhere is what I'm guessing.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs, thanks for taking the time to respond. It wasn't pure sql that I was working on, but a reporting service that uses SQL. And, I got to know from their support that they currently do not support correlated subqueries. They also suggested me an alternate solution, which does the job. Thanks again :)